# Delay background image and stop it from being cached

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress, caching, delay

I have a background image set to appear in place of/behind an ad slot, in case of ad blocking. However, I need to delay it until after the ad has shown.

I use the following code, however, the image is not delayed long enough.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var resources = {div1:"url('/images/image1.png')",div2:"url('/images/image2.jpg')"};
function loadImageBG(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = resources[id];
}
</script>
```

Also, how may I stop the image from being cached?

This is a WP site, and I'm using WP Super Cache; I see no function within the plugin to do this, though even so, I'm not sure this would be sufficient for browsers cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, robust way would be a timer.  Given the vagaries of unknown ad loading time -- and whether it loads at all -- it won't be perfect.  But it's a lot simpler than trying to determine when or if the ad loads.

Try something like:

```
function loadImageBG (id) {
    setTimeout ( function () {
        document.getElementById (id).style.backgroundImage = resources[id];
    }, 888);
}
```

I recommend not trying to stop the cache; you don't want to annoy your users *too* much. ;)

But, one way to do that is to append unique parameters to the resource URL:

```
function loadImageBG (id) {
    setTimeout ( function () {
        var d           = new Date();
        var milliSecs   = d.getTime();
        var noCacheURL  = resources[id].replace (/'\)/, "?nc=" + milliSecs + "')");

        document.getElementById (id).style.backgroundImage = noCacheURL;
    }, 888);
}
```

---

Notes:

1. `888` is the timer delay in milliseconds.  For usability reasons, I recommend not making this larger than `1000` -- which is 1 second.
2. There is no `noCacheURL` delay value.  Because `noCacheURL`s value is set by the millisecond clock, it's value will always be different with every page load.

   Thus, the user's browser will always request a fresh copy, bypassing the user's cache.

   If you are using a dynamically generated image (seems doubtful) and caching *that* server-side, then its timeout is a different question that you would need to ask separately.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try and reply back.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance; is '888' the delay time value?. Also, how/where do I set the noCacheURL delay value?